# AWS Glue Union S3 csv files

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I will be outputting many tables from 2 source systems as csv files into 2 different S3 buckets.  Each S3 bucket may have the same table names and schemas, but the data inside may be different.

For example,
Table 1 in S3 bucket #1 - contains sales from 2010-2015
Table 1 in S3 bucket #2 - contains sales range 2016-2022

Table 2 in S3 bucket #1 - contains customer data, last name A-M
Table 2 in S3 bucket #2 - contains customer data, last name N-Z

etc..

I want to Union the 2 S3 buckets where the bucket1.tablename = bucket2.tablename and then send this 'Unioned' file to another S3 bucket.  Each S3 bucket for each source will have thousands of tables.

This is the code I have.  It errors on the Union because there are tables/files with different schemas.

```
# Script generated for node Source 1
Source1_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(format_options={"quoteChar": "\"", "withHeader": True, "separator": ","}, connection_type="s3", format="csv", connection_options={"paths": ["s3://fredg-s3-bucket-test/poc/source1_files/"], "recurse": True}, transformation_ctx="Source1_node1")

# Script generated for node Source 2
Source2_node1665168246449 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(format_options={"quoteChar": "\"", "withHeader": True, "separator": ","}, connection_type="s3", format="csv", connection_options={"paths": ["s3://fredg-s3-bucket-test/poc/source2_files/"], "recurse": True}, transformation_ctx="Source2_node1665168246449")

# Script generated for node Union
Union_node1665168749539 = sparkUnion(glueContext, unionType = "DISTINCT", mapping = {"source1": Source2_node1665168246449, "source2": Source1_node1}, transformation_ctx = "Union_node1665168749539")

# Script generated for node ApplyMapping
ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame=Union_node1665168749539, mappings=[("ID", "long", "ID", "long"), ("Name", "string", "Name", "string"), ("Title", "string", "Title", "string")], transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2")

# Script generated for node Custom Transform
CustomTransform_node1665173509352 = MyTransform(glueContext, DynamicFrameCollection({"ApplyMapping_node2": ApplyMapping_node2}, glueContext))

# Script generated for node S3 bucket
S3bucket_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=ApplyMapping_node2, connection_type="s3", format="csv", connection_options={"path": "s3://fredg-s3-bucket-test/poc/targetfiles/", "partitionKeys": []}, transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node3")
```

How can I use AWS Glue/pyspark code to loop through both S3 buckets and union the tables with the same name?

Comment: You should try first and then share the code where you need help. But basically what you need to do is create 1 data frame from each location, using read_csv(). Then you can use just the join, union or merge command depends on your needs

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.